# R Conditionally Alter String

Tags: r, string

This seems like a simple question, but I have not been able to successfully google it.  I have two vectors of strings that I would like to combine based on a 3rd vector of `TRUE FALSE`.

Example:

```
strvec1 <- c("str1", "str2", "str3")
strvec2 <- c("alt1", "alt2", "alt3")
boolvec <- c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)
```

I would like for to call `somefunction(strvec1, strvec2, boolvec)` and for the result to be `c("str1", "str2", "alt3")`.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option would be just

```
somefunction <- function(x, y, z) ifelse(z, y, x)

somefunction(strvec1, strvec2, boolvec)
## [1] "str1" "str2" "alt3"
```

Answer (score 1):

If the strvectors are the same length, you can do:

```
cbind(strvec1, strvec2)[cbind(seq_along(strvec1), boolvec+1)]
# [1] "str1" "str2" "alt3"
```

And in a function:

```
f <- function(x,y,z) cbind(x, y)[cbind(seq_along(x), z+1L)]
f(strvec1, strvec2, boolvec)
# [1] "str1" "str2" "alt3"
```

Another option would be `replace`:

```
f2 <- function(x, y, z) replace(x, which(z), y[z])
f2(strvec1, strvec2, boolvec)
# [1] "str1" "str2" "alt3"
```

Here's a little comparison - only as rough indication:

```
strvec1 <- sample(letters, 1e6, T)
strvec2 <- sample(letters, 1e6, T)
boolvec <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 1e6, T)
somefunction <- function(x, y, z) ifelse(z, y, x)
f <- function(x,y,z) cbind(x, y)[cbind(seq_along(x), z+1L)]
system.time(somefunction(strvec1, strvec2, boolvec))
#       User      System     elapsed 
#      0.494       0.025       0.519 
system.time(f(strvec1, strvec2, boolvec))
#       User      System     elapsed 
#      0.048       0.008       0.056 
system.time(f2(strvec1, strvec2, boolvec))
#       User      System     elapsed 
#      0.048       0.002       0.050
```

Comment: Thank you -- this also works.  I accepted the other answer because it was a bit simpler.

Comment: I see.  In my case, I am just trying to append *'s to some coefficients that are statistically significant.  The other way my code will be more readable.  But I understand your point that this might be better if the application is large scale.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `somefunction` you want is `ifelse`:

```
strvec1 <- c("str1", "str2", "str3")
strvec2 <- c("alt1", "alt2", "alt3")
boolvec <- c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)

ifelse(boolvec, strvec2, strvec1)
# [1] "str1" "str2" "alt3"
```

NB: Note the order of `strvec1` and `strvec2`. `TRUE` maps to the second (`if`) argument and `FALSE` maps to the third (`else`) argument.